# Will keeping a WaterBath help prevent Overheating during summer in Cockatiels?

Tags: health, birds, cockatiels, weather, cooling

Maybe overheating was a word too strong to describe what is happening with my cockatiel. She seems to stick her tongue in and out in constant, rapid motion in order to dissipate heat into the air. I'm almost very sure this is overheating and nothing more because when I take her under a fan or take her to an air-conditioned place, she stops. To provide more context, place where I live in averages in temperature around 92 °F / 32 °C.

Constantly ventilating the room by having windows open seems to be a good option. Periodic showers too. There's no cooler place at home. But ventilating room doesn't seem to be sufficient enough and since summer's just started here, it's imminent that temperature spikes by at least a degree or two later in May.

I am thinking of keeping a water bath inside the cage, not only she would be able to use it for cooling by direct contact with water, but it would also provide evaporative cooling of the cage. Will this work?

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is important to recognize the signs of an overheating bird:

- He breathes Ford with the beak open
- He holds his wings away from his body
- It can end up on the ground
- It keeps the plumage plated
- He behaves in a stressed manner

Reading you, I see that you have already caught some good reflexes. However, they are careful not to force-bathe their parrot as the water that is too cold on the hot body can cause death from hydrocution.
I can give you some solutions to help your bird during periods of great heat:

- Keep your parrot in the shade, especially if you decide to take it outside to get some fresh air
- Bring fresh water several times during the day
- Give him fresh fruits and vegetables
- It is also important to refresh your environment. Putting a water bath is a good idea, you just have to be careful that the water is not too deep for the bird.
- Offer him "water games". For example, you can give it moistened vegetables (salads, leafy branches, etc.), ice cubes which will amuse your bird or give it toys in a shallow cup of water.